# SQL Query Order By for Parent-Child Relationship with sortorder

Tags: mysql, sql, dhtmlx

First, I use DHTMLX GANTT Chart for my project.

I use mysql database for load data to the chart and I am having a problem with SQL at the moment. (again)

I want to show the chart data to new page with a parent-child relationship of DHTMLX GANTT SQL Struture.

This is MySQL Structure and Data I have now

```
id          text            parent  sortorder
------------------------------------------------
1           Project #1      0       7
2           Task #1         1       5
3           Task #2         1       7
4           Task #3         1       6
5           Task #1.1       2       7
6           Task #1.2       2       1
7           Task #2.1       3       7
8           Task #2.2       3       2
```

and this is the result show in my Gantt Chart (I drag Task #3 upper than Task #2)

```
id          text            parent  sortorder
------------------------------------------------
1           Project #1      0       7
2           Task #1         1       5
5           Task #1.1       2       1
6           Task #1.2       2       7
4           Task #3         1       6
3           Task #2         1       7
7           Task #2.1       3       2
8           Task #2.2       3       7
```

To show the same order of Gantt Chart in new Page, How I should write sql query to show the same result?

I tried to use parent-child relationship query that found on Google but I get the wrong result.

Comment: Have you checked this article https://docs.dhtmlx.com/gantt/desktop__server_side.html#storingtheorderoftasks 
Or any articles from here https://docs.dhtmlx.com/gantt/desktop__howtostart_php.html#storingtheorderoftasks ? Each of them have a paragraph named `Storing the order of tasks` with a code sample.

Please show the code you use to load tasks and to update tasks order.

There code samples and working demos on github in dhtmlxgantt docs, so right now it's not clear from your question whether you're having trouble with one of those samples, or you need something completely different